# iPhone distance from current location as subtitle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am trying to find distance from selectedAnnotation to userLocation. I added the following code in the annotation NSObject:

```
-(void) setDistanceFromCurrentLocation:(CLLocation *)currentLocation{

CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.latitude longitude:self.longitude];

[self setDistance:[currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location2]];
}

- (NSString *)subtitle
{
NSString *myDistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f from current location", distance];
return myDistance;
}
```

Now in the didUpdatedidUpdateToLocation I tried using the following logic from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10881683/984248

Still getting 0.0 back. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

So I am calculating the distance from current location correctly now. But how do I pass this on to set it as the subtitle to a pin?

Here is how I am finding distance:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

[self setCurrentLocation:newLocation];

// if not Current Location then update the currently displayed Dealer Annotation
for (int i=0; i<self.dataArray.count; i++){

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *array = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Locations"];

    for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++){

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];

        CLLocation *pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue]];

        [?????? setDistance:[self.currentLocation distanceFromLocation:pinLocation]];
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how I am adding pins to the map:

```
for (int i=0; i<self.dataArray.count; i++){

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *array = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Locations"];

    for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++){

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];

        MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];

        annotation.latitude = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
        annotation.longitude = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude =
            annotation.latitude, .longitude =  annotation.longitude};
        MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord};

        annotation.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];

        annotation.subtitle = ?????;
        annotation.coordinate = region.center;

        //Saving the dictionary of the pin to show contact info later
        annotation.sourceDictionary = dictionary;
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you setting self.latitude & self.longitude?

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering, is currentLocation set to self.latitude,self.longitude?

in which case you would be trying to find the distance from yourself. Try logging the latitude and longitude values of the currentLocation parameter and the self.latitude and self.longitude variables, and make sure they are different.

If they are, then try logging [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location2] to see if it is non zero, if it is, then your setDistance method is the problem.

Other than that all I can think of is your distance variable is getting set to 0 somewhere else, or it is a variable that does not format with %1.1f so the formatter is setting it to 0.0