# generate multiple pin in specific distance in MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have one view controller with `MKMapview` and one array of multiple latitude and longitude. I want to show pin in map with in 5 mile distance from user location. How do I implement it?

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: Then, post what have you tried. :)

Comment: you are right but right now i have nothing to show you what i have tried.can you help me to start from beginning ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879579/how-to-calculate-distance-from-user-location-to-annotation-when-user-moves

I had tried from this demo but I think by my mi-stack it was not working for me

Comment: You have multiple tutorials, it's hard to find somebody on SO to give you all necessary code. Please consider the following : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Maps_on_the_iPhone_with_MapKit_and_the_MKMapView_Class or http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial. Also, SO is for help improving your "existing" code and solving possible errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

**Put this code in viewdidLoad method and give distance filter where you want to update your location**

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
/* Pinpoint our location with the following accuracy:
 *
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation  highest + sensor data
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyBest               highest     
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters   10 meters   
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters      100 meters
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer          1000 meters 
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers    3000 meters
 */
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

**Drop pin annotation.**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    // Add an annotation
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"Where am I?";
    point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";
    
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: I am sorry but I want complete instruction this is my first application so i have no any idea. and thanks for giving me replay.

Comment: okay do one thing you can just go through this tutorial if you are new for Map pin annotation http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-drop-a-pin-on-map-with-mapkit-api/